# Drawing rotated triangles

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to change a triangle that displays like this:

```
  x  
 xxx  
xxxxx
```

to one that looks like this:

```
  x     
 xx
xxx 
 xx
  x
```

and

```
 x
 xx
 xxx
 xx
 x
```

It should have a user input that will change the size of the triangle like this:

```
        cout << "Please enter a size for the shape: ";
        cin >> size;

        for (int row = 1; row <= size; ++row)

        {
            for (int column = 1; column <= row; ++column)
                cout << '*';
            cout << endl;
        }
```

Sorry for any formatting errors, still new to programming in general. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to decompose this problem into easier ones. Instead of thinking about how to print the whole triangle, think about what is the property and the pattern that each row has.

With regards to the first tringle

```
  x  
 xxx  
xxxxx
```

You can notice that it is simmetrical wrt the y axis. This leaves you with printing two copies of the following:

```
  x
 xx
xxx
```

That it's much easier to print. 
You also notice that each row `i` is composed as follows:
`size-i` spaces followed by `i` consecutive `x`, allowing you to print a single row by printing a number of spaces first follows by a number of `x` followed by again other spaces.

Try something as the following and adapt it for the other cases you mentioned:

```
int main()
{
     int size = 0;
     cout << "Please enter a size for the shape: ";
     cin >> size;
     cout << endl;
     for (int row = 1; row <= size; ++row)
     {
         //-------first half
         //spaces
         for (int column = 1; column <= size-row; ++column)
             cout<<" ";
         //points
         for (int column = 1; column <= row ; ++column)
             cout << '*';
         //-------second half
         //points
         for (int column = 1; column <= row-1 ; ++column)
             cout << '*';
         //spaces
         for (int column = 1; column <= size-row; ++column)
             cout<<" ";

         cout << endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/47fAKEUGJ5dFAzjw)

Answer (score 0):

The below code draws triangle with stars. Height is the height of the triangle and length is the number of character at the base.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int Length = 10;
    const int Height=5;

    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++) 
    {

        for (int j = 0; j <Length/2-i; j++)
        {

            cout << " ";


        }

        int NumberOfStars=2*i+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfStars; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }


        cout <<  endl;
    }

     return 0;

 }
```

[Run the code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c7e0c60034cee70)

Answer (score 0):

You should output  and `*` separated.

The following `code` could work of three cases:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){

    int size;
    std::cout << "Please enter a size for the shape: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    std::cout << "case 1: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size - 1 - row; ++col)
            std::cout << ' ';
        for (int col = 0; col < 2 * row + 1; ++col)
            std::cout << "*";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "case 2: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size - 1 - row; ++col)
            std::cout << ' ';
        for (int col = 0; col < row + 1; ++col)
            std::cout << "*";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < row; ++col)
            std::cout << ' ';
        for (int col = 0; col < size - row; ++col)
            std::cout << "*";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "case 3: " << std::endl << std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < row + 1; ++col)
            std::cout << "*";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size - row; ++col)
            std::cout << "*";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, but `case 2` and `case 3` both display the medium series asterisks twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is different kinds of outputs with assumption of the size of `3`:

The following code will display the output:

```
*
**
***
```

```
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

If you want to print a triangle like output as shown below, then use the code below:

```
  * 
 ***
*****
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = size - i - 1; j > 0; j --)
        std::cout<<" ";
    for(int k = (i * 2) + 1; k > 0; k--)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

And finally to print the output as you asked, then use the code below:

```
  *
 **
***
 **
  *

*
**
***
**
*
```

```
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
    for(int j = size - i; j > 0; j--)
        std::cout<<" ";
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
for(int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = size - i; j > 0; j--)
        std::cout<<" ";
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
for(int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        std::cout<<"*";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.